# how can I add lombok jar into intellij idea without installing plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I was working on a spring boot project using eclipse. I'm trying to shift to intellij idea but there is lombok jar that our project uses. Due to restrictions from network connection I can't download and install lombok plugin. I can able to connect lombok jar with eclipse. But not sure how to connect the lombok jar with intellij idea. I searched online, didn't find solution.
Please help me with this one.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code will compile fine without the plugin but your IDE will not understand what Lombok is doing. It will show errors when you use Lombok-generated methods like getters. It will not give you auto-completion. **You need the plugin to work productively.**

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thanks for you quick reply. Yes my project using getters and setters from Lombok so it's not compiling. And as per the plugin part I can't download from intellij.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can visit Github project page of Lombok Plugin for Intellij Idea at here:
https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/
and following the instruction:

> Manually: Download the [latest release](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/releases/latest) and install it manually using
>
> Preferences > Plugins > Install plugin from disk...
>
> Restart IDE.

> Required IntelliJ Configuration
>
> In your project: `Click Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler, Annotation Processors`.
>
> Click `Enable Annotation Processing`

> Afterwards you might need to do a complete rebuild of your project via `Build -> Rebuild Project`.

- Note: Lombok project dependency in build tool Gradle/Maven...

Comment: Hi @Duc Vo thanks for your quick reply. Of all the sites git is something my network won't allow. So can't download from Git too